# How to present a modal view controller with fixed UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I am trying to set up a Modal View Controller, that that lies below a fixed toolbar. therefore the toolbar is supposed to stay on top while the modal view rolls in. 
the Safari-App does that for example, when hitting the bookmarks-button. the toolbar stays, the buttons change..

I tried a couple of things like pushing the toolbar to the front and ended up not using the presentModalViewController method at all, and animating the new View manually into a subview instead. but that brought a couple of other issues along.

Comment: If you are using 3.0, take a look at the beta documentation.  The toolbar got some updates that make what you want easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are saying, when you press add bookmark in safari, a new modal view shows with no tool bar. The navigation bar at the top is not a tool bar if that is what you mean. They are UIToolbarItem set into self.navigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

All modal views I've seen are animated until they take up the whole of the screen. Those modal-like views that only scroll up to a certain point in some apps, are done by hand. Maybe you can cover those issues encountered when doing this by hand in another post?